# How to compare and retrieve item in different table from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 tables (Requests and driversWorking). Every Requests child (riderId) will have different phone number. How do I retrieve current riderId from current Requests key in order to retrieve riderId location (longitude and latitude) from driversWorking table.

Below is my database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using nested queries. Assuming you have a node named `users` and is in the same time a direct child of your Firebase root and assuming that `driversWorking` is also a direct child of your Firebase root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = userIdRef.child("users").child(userId);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String riderId = dataSnapshot.child("riderId").getValue(String.class);

        DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("driversWorking").child(driverId).child("l");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    double zero = ds.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
                    double one = ds.child("1").getValue(Double.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", zero + " / " + one);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `userId` is the id of the logged in user and `driverId` is the id of the driver. In the example you gave, can be `0163640500`.